# Special character and number chars printing as weird values

Tags: c++

I am passing chars into a string and jumbling the letters in the string using a function however the chars grabbed from the arrays at the top of main are printing as an accented u for symbols and a % sign for numbers, the letters however are unaffected. Help appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void scrambleString(string str)
{
    int x = str.length();
    for (int y = x; y > 0; y--)
    {
        int pos = rand() % x;
        char tmp = str[y - 1];
        str[y - 1] = str[pos];
        str[pos] = tmp;
    }
    cout << str;
}

int main()
{
    // Arrays for RNG to work with //
    char letters[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
        'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
        's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    char symbols[] = { '!', '£', '$', '%', '&', '*', '@', '~' };

    char numbers[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    // Other Variables //
    int letterIn;
    int specialIn;
    int numberIn;
    string randomPass;
    string holdString;

    cout << "No of Letters:  ";
    cin >> letterIn;
    cout << "No of Special char:  ";
    cin >> specialIn;
    cout << "No of Numbers:  ";
    cin >> numberIn;

    // Letters
    for (int i = 0; i < letterIn; i++)
    {
        int RNG = rand() % 26;
        char holdChar = letters[RNG];
        // Convert to String
        holdString.insert(i, 1, holdChar);

    }
    // Symbols
    for (int i = 0; i < specialIn; i++)
    {
        int RNG = rand() % 8;
        char holdChar = symbols[RNG];
        // Convert to String
        holdString.insert(letterIn, 1, holdChar);
    }
    // Numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < numberIn; i++)
    {
        int RNG = rand() % 8;
        char holdChar = symbols[RNG];
        // Convert to String
        holdString.insert(letterIn+specialIn, 1, holdChar);
    }
    cout << holdString << endl;
    scrambleString(holdString);
}
```

Comment: Can you, please, post an example output?

Comment: Note that `'£'` is not defined in ASCII; this character may need to be wide to be interpreted correctly as Unicode. For the sake of simplicity, it might be better to omit it entirely.

Comment: The example produces the output that I would expect, if I omit `'£'` and reduce the modulo in `// Symbols` to match. Consider using `sizeof` instead of constants.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/7wfq2 the first line is unscrambled the second line is scrambled

Comment: could you use an example of sizeof? im pretty new to c++ :)

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but the code would be a bit easier to read if instead of `hold_string.insert(..., holdChar)` you used `hold_string.push_back(holdChar)`.

Comment: @Kingpin [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size of an object or type. For example, `sizeof(symbols);` returns 8 and `sizeof(char);` returns 1.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys, implementing them into my code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the last for loop at the end

```
  // Numbers
  for (int i = 0; i < numberIn; i++)
  {
```

specifically this line:

```
        char holdChar = symbols[RNG];
```

This should be `char holdChar = numbers[RNG];`

ALSO as was pointed out in the comments '£' needs to be removed from your code because it isn't an ascii character.

Comment: Haha okay turns out it's a silly mistake but thank you very much for pointing it out for me! everything is working now :)